# custom relationship name salesforce

Tags: relationships, queryexception

I want to make a custom relation between `Opportunity` and `Account`.

***I want to retrieve the account who makes the opportunity***

So I wrote this:

```
"SELECT Id, RecordType.Name, Name, Description, StageName, CloseDate, Type, IsClosed, IsWon,HasOpportunityLineItem, Pricebook2.Name , Owner.Sales_representative_code__c
           , Owner.FirstName, Owner.LastName, Shipping_method__c, Payment_method_code__c, Payment_terms_code__c, Consumables__c, End_date__c, Start_date__c, Expected_delivery_date__c
           , Pricing_model__c, Customer_insights__c,Shipping_cost_at_our_expense__c,
    (
      SELECT  Customer_code__c,Name,Payment_method_code__c,Payment_terms_code__c, Blocked__c, VAT_Code__c, TIN__c
                    ,Owner.Sales_representative_code__c, Owner.FirstName, Owner.LastName, Primary_contact__r.Contact_person_code__c
                   , Primary_contact__r.FirstName, Primary_contact__r.LastName 
     FROM Account            
    )
     FROM Opportunity
    WHERE Opportunity.IsClosed = true
          AND Opportunity.IsWon = true
          AND Opportunity.HasOpportunityLineItem = true
"
```

But I got this error in output:

> Didn't understand relationship 'Account__r' in FROM part of query
>   call. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to
>   append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference
>   your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.'

What's wrong?

thanks in advance.

Comment: @AlexanderBerehovskiy same error.

Comment: can you please update your question with more details: what custom relationship do you have. what are API names of that relationship

Comment: @AlexanderBerehovskiy I updated the question. The api name are declared with  "__c" the others are standard fields.

Comment: you are saying "I want to make a custom relation between Opportunity and Account." have you already created this field on Opportunity?

Comment: @AlexanderBerehovskiy Yes. I created an opportunity related with an account ,in salesforce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mistaken the relationship between the Opportunity and the Account.

In fact, the opportunity has a relationship to an Account.

The query you're using tries to query all the accounts related to the opportunity. But there is only one.

Here's the right query:

```
SELECT Id, RecordType.Name, Name, Description, StageName, CloseDate, Type, IsClosed, IsWon,HasOpportunityLineItem, Pricebook2.Name , Owner.Sales_representative_code__c
           , Owner.FirstName, Owner.LastName, Shipping_method__c, Payment_method_code__c, Payment_terms_code__c, Consumables__c, End_date__c, Start_date__c, Expected_delivery_date__c
           , Pricing_model__c, Customer_insights__c,Shipping_cost_at_our_expense__c,
Account.Customer_code__c,Account.Name,Account.Payment_method_code__c,Account.Payment_terms_code__c, Account.Blocked__c, Account.VAT_Code__c, Account.TIN__c
                    ,Account.Owner.Sales_representative_code__c, Account.Owner.FirstName, Account.Owner.LastName, Account.Primary_contact__r.Contact_person_code__c
                   , Account.Primary_contact__r.FirstName, Account.Primary_contact__r.LastName 
     FROM Opportunity
    WHERE Opportunity.IsClosed = true
          AND Opportunity.IsWon = true
          AND Opportunity.HasOpportunityLineItem = true
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried your query. It works, but in correspondant of the account field i see null values. How is it possible?

Comment: How are you using the opportunities returned by the query after?

Comment: i want only to retrieve the fields. I don't want to make 3 separate queries for achieve that. is it possible to retrieve `Account` and `owner` fields by a giving `opportunity`?

Comment: Of course this is possible. This is what you're doing in your query.